# Expand AD Group using Scala

Tags: java, scala, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to expand a bunch of AD Groups using Scala. Based on the code given here

http://www.thetekblog.com/2010/06/active-directory-with-ldap-retrieving-all-members-of-a-group/

I wrote the following code

```
package com.abhi

import java.util
import javax.naming.ldap._
import javax.naming._
import java.util.Hashtable
import javax.naming.directory.{SearchControls, SearchResult}
object LDAPScala extends App {
   val base = "ou=Foo,dc=MYCOMPANY,dc=COM"
   val env = new util.Hashtable[String, String]()
   env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory")
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple")
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "foo@mycompany.com")
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Bar")
   env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldapserver.mycompany.com:389")
   val groupList = List("Group1", "Group2", "Group3")

   try {
      val ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null)
      val searchCtls = new SearchControls()
      searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE)
      val attributes = Array("member","memberof")
      searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(attributes);

      for {
         group <- groupList
      } {
         val searchFilter = s"(&(objectCategory=group)(name=${group}))"
         val answers = ctx.search(base, searchFilter, searchCtls)
         while(answers.hasMoreElements) {
            val answer = answers.next()
            val attributes = answer.getAttributes.getAll
            while(attributes.hasMore) {
               val attr = attributes.nextElement()
               val everyone = attr.getAll
               while(everyone.hasMore) {
                val person = everyone.next()
                println(person)
               }
            }
         }
      }
   } catch {
      case e : Exception =>
         println(e.getMessage)
         println(e.getStackTrace)
   }
}
```

This code works and I can see a list of users in each group like this

```
CN=User1,OU=Users,OU=Accounts,OU=tor,OU=CA,OU=AMER,OU=Regions,DC=FOO,DC=COM
CN=User2,OU=Users,OU=Accounts,OU=LON,OU=UK,OU=EMEA,OU=Regions,DC=FOO,DC=COM
CN=User3,OU=Users,OU=Accounts,OU=pla,OU=US,OU=AMER,OU=Regions,DC=FOO,DC=COM
```

Three questions

1. I needed the login IDs (I think they are called samAccountNames). but here the CN contains the  actual names of people not their login ids.
2. Will this give me all the members? I remember that AD had some type of limitation where it will truncate the number of users in the group if there are too many users.
3. I don't know if my code above will work if there are groups within groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to convert the CNs to samAccountNames. The final code is

```
package com.abhi
import java.util
import javax.naming.ldap._
import javax.naming._
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object LDAPScala extends App {
   val base = "dc=FOO,dc=COM"
   val env = new util.Hashtable[String, String]()
   env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory")
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple")
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user@foo.com")
   env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pass")
   env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://adserver.foo.com:389")
   val groupList = List("group1", "group2", "group3")

   try {
      val people = for {
         group <- groupList
         cn <- queryAD(base, s"(&(objectCategory=group)(name=${group}))", "member")
         sam <- queryAD(cn, "(sAMAccountName=*)", "samaccountname")
         name <- getName(cn)
      } yield (group, sam, name)
      people.foreach{case (g, s, n) => println(s"$g,$s,$n")}
   } catch {
      case e : Exception =>
         println(e.getMessage)
         println(e.getStackTrace)
   }

   def getName(cn: String): Option[String] = {
      val regex = """^CN=([\w\s\d]*),.*$""".r
      cn match {
         case regex(name) => Some(name)
         case _ => None
      }
   }

   def queryAD(base: String, searchFilter: String, attribute: String): List[String] = {
      val ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null)
      val searchCtls = new SearchControls()
      searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE)
      searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(Array(attribute))
      val answers = ctx.search(base, searchFilter, searchCtls)
      var retVal = ArrayBuffer[String]()
      while(answers.hasMoreElements) {
         val answer = answers.next()
         val member = answer.getAttributes.get(attribute).getAll
         while(member.hasMoreElements) {
            val person = member.next().toString
            retVal += person
         }
      }
      retVal.toList
   }
}
```